# A geometric characterization of affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Assume that $M$ is  a  submanifold  of  $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the  following  property:

For  every $x\in M$ and  $y \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus M$, the  open straight line $\{tx+(1-t)y\mid t \in (0,1)\}$ does  not intersect $M$.

> Does this  imply that $M$ is  a whole  affine sub space?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is yes. Here's a sketch.

The crucial observation is this: Whenever $p,q\in M$, the line $\ell=\overleftrightarrow{pq}$ is entirely contained in $M$. First note that the points past $q$ on $\overrightarrow{pq}$ must all be in $M$ (if not, choosing such a point $r\notin M$, the line segment $\overline pr$ contains $q\in M$). By symmetry, all the points past $p$ on $\overleftarrow{pq}$ must be in $M$. Last, the points of $\ell$ between $p$ and $q$ must all be in $M$, as well (choose such a point $r\notin M$ and $s\in M$ past $q$).

Now consider the intersection $\mathscr S$ of $M$ with a small sphere $S^{n-1}$ centered at $p\in M$. (This must be a nonempty $(k-1)$-dimensional manifold if we pick a generic radius.) From what we've said, the lines $\overleftrightarrow{pq}$ are all contained in $M$ for $q\in\mathscr S$. For any $q,r\in\mathscr S$, joining $p$ to all the points of $\overleftrightarrow{qr}$, we subtend a $2$-dimensional sphere contained in $\mathscr S$. Picking further points, we must in fact have an entire $(k-1)$-dimensional sphere contained in $\mathscr S$. This means that $M$ lies in an affine $k$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Here's perhaps a little cleaner alternative second half of the answer. Suppose $\ell \in T_pM$ is a tangent line at $p$. Pick a sequence $p_n$ of points converging to $p$, joining them we get lines $\ell_n$ "converging" to $\ell$. By the first half, $\ell_n \subset M$ for all $n$. Note that "converging" means for any $q \in \ell$, there's a sequence $q_n \in \ell_n$ of points converging to $q$...

Comment: ...Let $B \subset \Bbb R^n$ be a ball around $p$ such that $(B, B \cap M)$ is an embedded chart, homeomorphic to $(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^k)$. Choose $q \in B \cap \ell \subset B$. Then $q_n$ is a sequence of points in $B \cap M$ converging to $q$; but $B \cap M$ is closed in $B$ because of the chart condition, hence $q \in B \cap M$. To sum up, two points $p$ and $q$ of $\ell$ are contained in $M$ - that means $\ell$ is contained in $M$. Hence, $T_p M \subset M$ and by dimension arguments, $T_p M = M$.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Prof Shifrin Thank you very much for your very interesting answer.

Comment: I don't know much about manifold, But  I believe that if a set contains the line passing through each pair of its points, then the set is affine. And it can be written in the form of a translation of a vector subspace, equivalently $\{x \in R^n ~ | \quad Ax=b\}$ , Why do we need about the second half argument of proof?!

Comment: @nonlinearthought So you contend that any convex set is an affine subspace?  Consider a ball.

Comment: you think balls contain lines !!

Comment: Ok, so I misread. So you need to prove what you think is obvious. I wrote the hard part of my proof because it was far from obvious to me.

Comment: I  did, See my answer..........

Comment: @nonlinearthought Your proof is good (+1). Regarding "Why do we need about the second half argument of proof?!", it is simply because the answerer originally came up with this approach. Surely just about proof can be simplified/modified, and you did so. The "why" question doesn't really have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @BalarkaSen The reason I asked why is that, when I accidentally encountered with this question, I guessed, it shouldn't have an answer more that two or three lines!  But when I saw the answer , It looked too complicated for me  (since I know a little about Manifolds), I thought perhaps there is something that I am missing.  I didn't mean rude at all!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. First, it is not hard to show that $M$ contains lines passing through each pair of its points. Now pick  $ a \in M $. We will show that $L = M - a $ (sum of two sets in [Minkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition)'s sense)is a vector subspace of $R^n.$

Proof: Note that $L$ contains $0$ and it contains all line passing through its points. Now take $x,y \in L$ and $t \in R.$ Want to show that $x+ty \in L$. To end this, note that $2x \in L$, since the line passing through $0$ and $x$ entirely belongs to $L$. Similarly $2ty \in M.$ Due to convexity of $M$(which implies the convexity of L)  we have 
$$\frac{1}{2} (2x) +\frac{1}{2} (2ty) = x+ty \in L$$
Therefore $L$ is a vector subspace, thus for a suitable matrix, say $A$ we have $L=\{x \in R^n ~ | \quad  Ax=0  \}$ , Thus $M=L+a = \{x ~| \quad Ax=b \}$ where $b=Aa$.

Comment: I'll think about this, but you should not write $M-\{a\}$. This would remove the point $a$ from $M$, not subtract the vector $a$ from all the vectors in $M$. You mean $M-a$. ... You don't need the last bit. An affine subspace is, quite simply, defined to be the translate of a vector subspace, so proving $L$ is a subspace and having $M=L+a$ does it. You certainly seem to be right that it's just simple algebra once one has my first paragraph.

Comment: @TedShifrin I modified it, however I myself think $M-\{a\}$ is more appropriate, Since follows the Minskowski sum of two sets $A-B$. I think The notation  $\setminus$ is widely used for set-minus  . The last line is just for those who take definition of affine sets in that manner, (I have seen in some optimization text books). I should add here that the answer I wrote here works for ANY arbitrary VECTOR SPACE $X$ no need a topology on it.